# Observable that continues emitting events after having emitted an error

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

As the contract says here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

> When an Observable does issue an OnCompleted or OnError notification,
>   the Observable may release its resources and terminate, and its
>   observers should not attempt to communicate with it any further.

In this snippet, I create an `Observable` that emits events even after emitting an error, and my `target` function allows to create another `Observable` from it that doesn't stop listening for events after an error occurs.

```js
const { of, interval, concat, throwError } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map, catchError } = rxjs.operators;

const source = interval(1000).pipe(
        map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)),
        switchMap(result => result < 6 ? of(result) : throwError(result)));

const target = source => source.pipe(catchError(err => concat(of('Error: ' + err), target(source))));

target(source).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

One use case for this snippet would be to create an autocomplete that doesn't stop working in case of an HTTP error. Is that an anti-pattern? Would it cause something like memory leaks or callstack growing forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge no, you just passing on the source observable so the subscription won't end.

In addition the source observable is a timed observable so it won't block the main thread. But if you replace `interval` with cold `of(something)` observable and the error is repeatable, your main thread will freeze

There is an cleaner pattern

```
source.pipe(catchError(err=>...of(err)),repeat())
```

Demo:

```js
const { of, interval, concat, throwError } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map, repeat, catchError } = rxjs.operators;

const source = interval(1000).pipe(
        map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)),
        switchMap(result => result < 6 ? of(result) : throwError(result)),
        catchError(err => of('Error: ' + err)),
        repeat());

source.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I allow myself to write a working snippet in your answer

Comment: Glad it helps, u can also add a limited number to repeat on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

That's totally fine to catch errors you want to handle and switch them to an other stream. You also can use `retry` operator to ensure that after N attempts it will finally fail.

The only note - don't forget to unsubscribe once you don't need it and it won't produce memory leaks.

The best case to handle it closer to the failure, then you don't need to return back the original stream or to use `repeat` / `retry` operators.

```js
const { of, interval, concat, throwError } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map, catchError } = rxjs.operators;

const source = searchTerm$.pipe(
  debounce(250),
  switchMap(term => this.http.get('/suggestion?=' + term).pipe(
    catchError(() => EMPTY), // won't break the parent stream of terms.
  ),
);

source.subscribe(console.log); // will receive emits until unsubscribe.
```

Comment: Becareful though, if map() throws, in ur code sample the error will not be caught.

Comment: it won't throw an error because it's math operations on numbers.

Comment: yes but what i am saying as a generic pattern. it won't be safe to assume your code produce an observable that won't be terminated.

Comment: In the same way we can assume that catchError can throw an error too and we need one more catchError.

Comment: Yes ur are right but that’s not the point though. There is no catch all feature in ur stream

Comment: The question is about autocomplete and failure of the request. Therefore it makes sense to catch error in the request pipe. Because we expect this error. Instead of catching all errors that can bring app to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: In real life situation I won’t implement a stream like that tbh, I rather catch all and handle different error accordingly

Comment: Up to you, I would do it exactly as it's in the answer.